I implement red-black tree in C language and output it as a TXT file, but TREE is not output after deleting it
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum { RED, BLACK } nodeColor;

typedef struct rbnode {
    int key;
    nodeColor color;
    struct rbnode* left, * right, * parent;
} rbnode;

typedef struct QueueNode {
    rbnode* data;
    struct QueueNode* next;
} QueueNode;

typedef struct {
    QueueNode* front;
    QueueNode* rear;
} Queue;

// Queue 관련 함수들
Queue* createQueue() {
    Queue* q = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    q->front = q->rear = NULL;
    return q;
}

void enqueue(Queue* q, rbnode* data) {
    QueueNode* newNode = (QueueNode*)malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (q->rear == NULL) {
        q->front = q->rear = newNode;
    }
    else {
        q->rear->next = newNode;
        q->rear = newNode;
    }
}

rbnode* dequeue(Queue* q) {
    if (q->front == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    QueueNode* temp = q->front;
    rbnode* data = temp->data;
    q->front = q->front->next;
    if (q->front == NULL) {
        q->rear = NULL;
    }
    free(temp);
    return data;
}

// 함수 프로토타입 선언
rbnode* newNode(int key);
void leftRotate(rbnode** root, rbnode* x);
void rightRotate(rbnode** root, rbnode* x);
void insert(rbnode** root, rbnode* x);
void insertFixup(rbnode** root, rbnode* x);
void delete(rbnode** root, rbnode* z);
void deleteFixup(rbnode** root, rbnode* x);
rbnode* searchNode(rbnode* root, int key);
void printInorder(rbnode* root, FILE* fout);
void printLevelorder(rbnode* root, FILE* fout);
void freeRBTree(rbnode* root);


rbnode* newNode(int key) {
    rbnode* node = (rbnode*)malloc(sizeof(rbnode));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->parent = NULL;
    node->color = 'R'; // 새로운 노드는 레드로 삽입
    return node;
}

rbnode* searchNode(rbnode* root, int key) {
    rbnode* currentNode = root;
    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        if (key == currentNode->key) {
            return currentNode;
        }
        else if (key < currentNode->key) {
            currentNode = currentNode->left;
        }
        else {
            currentNode = currentNode->right;
        }
    }
    return NULL; // 해당 키를 가진 노드를 찾지 못한 경우
}

void BSTInsert(rbnode** root, rbnode* z) {
    rbnode* y = NULL;
    rbnode* x = *root;

    while (x != NULL) {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }

    z->parent = y;

    if (y == NULL)
        *root = z;
    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left = z;
    else
        y->right = z;
}

// 레드-블랙 트리 삽입
void leftRotate(rbnode** root, rbnode* x) {
    rbnode* y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    if (y->left != NULL) {
        y->left->parent = x;
    }
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == NULL) {
        *root = y;
    }
    else if (x == x->parent->left) {
        x->parent->left = y;
    }
    else {
        x->parent->right = y;
    }
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
}

void rightRotate(rbnode** root, rbnode* y) {
    rbnode* x = y->left;
    y->left = x->right;
    if (x->right != NULL) {
        x->right->parent = y;
    }
    x->parent = y->parent;
    if (y->parent == NULL) {
        *root = x;
    }
    else if (y == y->parent->right) {
        y->parent->right = x;
    }
    else {
        y->parent->left = x;
    }
    x->right = y;
    y->parent = x;
}

void insert(rbnode** root, rbnode* x) {
    // 새로운 노드 x를 이진 탐색 트리에 삽입
    rbnode* y = NULL;
    rbnode* z = *root;

    // 이진 탐색 트리에서 x의 위치를 찾음
    while (z != NULL) {
        y = z;
        if (x->key < z->key) {
            z = z->left;
        }
        else {
            z = z->right;
        }
    }
    x->parent = y;
    if (y == NULL) {
        *root = x; // 트리가 비어있을 경우 root로 설정
    }
    else if (x->key < y->key) {
        y->left = x;
    }
    else {
        y->right = x;
    }

    x->left = NULL;
    x->right = NULL;
    x->color = RED; // 새로운 노드는 레드로 삽입되므로 RB 특성을 위반하지 않음

    // 삽입 후 트리를 수정해야 할 필요가 있으므로 insertFixup 호출
    insertFixup(root, x);
}


void insertFixup(rbnode** root, rbnode* x) {
    while (x != *root && x->parent->color == RED) {
        if (x->parent == x->parent->parent->left) {
            rbnode* y = x->parent->parent->right; // uncle

            if (y != NULL && y->color == RED) {
                // Case 1: Uncle node y is red
                x->parent->color = BLACK;
                y->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->parent->color = RED;
                x = x->parent->parent;
            }
            else {
                // Case 2: Uncle node y is black and x is a right child
                if (x == x->parent->right) {
                    x = x->parent;
                    leftRotate(root, x);
                }

                // Case 3: Uncle node y is black and x is a left child
                x->parent->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->parent->color = RED;
                rightRotate(root, x->parent->parent);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Symmetric cases
            rbnode* y = x->parent->parent->left; // uncle

            if (y != NULL && y->color == RED) {
                // Case 1: Uncle node y is red
                x->parent->color = BLACK;
                y->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->parent->color = RED;
                x = x->parent->parent;
            }
            else {
                // Case 2: Uncle node y is black and x is a left child
                if (x == x->parent->left) {
                    x = x->parent;
                    rightRotate(root, x);
                }

                // Case 3: Uncle node y is black and x is a right child
                x->parent->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->parent->color = RED;
                leftRotate(root, x->parent->parent);
            }
        }
    }
    (*root)->color = BLACK; // Root node must be black
}

rbnode* treeMinimum(rbnode* x) {
    while (x->left != NULL) {
        x = x->left;
    }
    return x;
}


rbnode* treeSuccessor(rbnode* x) {
    if (x->right != NULL) {
        return treeMinimum(x->right);
    }
    rbnode* y = x->parent;
    while (y != NULL && x == y->right) {
        x = y;
        y = y->parent;
    }
    return y;
}


void delete(rbnode** root, rbnode* z) {
    if (z == NULL) return;

    rbnode* y, * x;
    if (z->left == NULL || z->right == NULL) {
        y = z;
    }
    else {
        y = treeSuccessor(z);
    }

    if (y->left != NULL) {
        x = y->left;
    }
    else {
        x = y->right;
    }

    if (x != NULL) {
        x->parent = y->parent;
    }

    if (y->parent == NULL) {
        *root = x;
    }
    else if (y == y->parent->left) {
        y->parent->left = x;
    }
    else {
        y->parent->right = x;
    }

    if (y != z) {
        z->key = y->key;
    }

    if (y->color == BLACK) {
        deleteFixup(root, x);
    }

    // 삭제한 노드의 부모 노드와의 연결을 끊음
    if (y->parent != NULL) {
        if (y->parent->left == y) {
            y->parent->left = NULL;
        }
        else {
            y->parent->right = NULL;
        }
    }

    free(y);
}



void deleteFixup(rbnode** root, rbnode* x) {
    rbnode* w;
    while (x != *root && x != NULL && x->color == BLACK) {
        if (x == x->parent->left) {
            w = x->parent->right;
            if (w->color == RED) {
                w->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->color = RED;
                leftRotate(root, x->parent);
                w = x->parent->right;
            }
            if (w->left->color == BLACK && w->right->color == BLACK) {
                w->color = RED;
                x = x->parent;
            }
            else {
                if (w->right->color == BLACK) {
                    w->left->color = BLACK;
                    w->color = RED;
                    rightRotate(root, w);
                    w = x->parent->right;
                }
                w->color = x->parent->color;
                x->parent->color = BLACK;
                w->right->color = BLACK;
                leftRotate(root, x->parent);
                x = *root; // 반복문 종료
            }
        }
        else {
            // Symmetric cases
            w = x->parent->left; // uncle

            if (w->color == RED) {
                // Case 1: Uncle node w is red
                w->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->color = RED;
                rightRotate(root, x->parent);
                w = x->parent->left;
            }

            if (w->right->color == BLACK && w->left->color == BLACK) {
                // Case 2: Uncle node w is black and both of w's children are black
                w->color = RED;
                x = x->parent;
            }
            else {
                if (w->left->color == BLACK) {
                    // Case 3: Uncle node w is black, w's left child is black, and w's right child is red
                    w->right->color = BLACK;
                    w->color = RED;
                    leftRotate(root, w);
                    w = x->parent->left;
                }
                // Case 4: Uncle node w is black, w's left child is red, and w's right child is black
                w->color = x->parent->color;
                x->parent->color = BLACK;
                w->left->color = BLACK;
                rightRotate(root, x->parent);
                x = *root; // 반복문 종료
            }
        }
    }
    if (x != NULL) {
        x->color = BLACK; // 루트 노드는 블랙으로 설정
    }
}


void printInorder(rbnode* root, FILE* fout) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        printInorder(root->left, fout); // 왼쪽 서브트리 출력
        fprintf(fout, "%d ", root->key); // 현재 노드 출력
        printInorder(root->right, fout); // 오른쪽 서브트리 출력
    }
}


void printLevelorder(rbnode* root, FILE* fout) {
    if (root == NULL) return;

    Queue* q = createQueue();
    enqueue(q, root);

    while (q->front != NULL) {
        rbnode* current = dequeue(q);
        fprintf(fout, "%d ", current->key);

        if (current->left != NULL) {
            enqueue(q, current->left);
        }
        if (current->right != NULL) {
            enqueue(q, current->right);
        }
    }
}

void printInorderToFile(rbnode* root, FILE* fout) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    printInorderToFile(root->left, fout);
    fprintf(fout, "%d ", root->key);
    printInorderToFile(root->right, fout);
}

void printLevelorderToFile(rbnode* root, FILE* fout) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    rbnode* queue[100];
    int front = 0, rear = 0;
    queue[rear++] = root;
    while (front < rear) {
        rbnode* node = queue[front++];
        fprintf(fout, "%d ", node->key);
        if (node->left != NULL) queue[rear++] = node->left;
        if (node->right != NULL) queue[rear++] = node->right;
    }
}

void freeRBTree(rbnode* node) {
    if (node == NULL) return;
    freeRBTree(node->left);
    freeRBTree(node->right);
    free(node);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s input.txt output.txt\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* fin = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // 입력 파일 열기
    FILE* fout = fopen(argv[2], "w"); // 출력 파일 열기
    if (!fin || !fout) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Red-Black Tree 생성
    rbnode* root = NULL;
    int key;

    // 입력 파일에서 데이터를 읽어서 Red-Black Tree에 삽입
    while (fscanf(fin, "%d", &key) != EOF) {
        // 중복된 값 제거
        if (searchNode(root, key) == NULL) {
            rbnode* n = newNode(key);
            insert(&root, n);
        }
    }

    // 삽입 후 결과 출력
    fprintf(fout, "");
    printInorder(root, fout);
    fprintf(fout, "\n");

    fprintf(fout, "");
    printLevelorder(root, fout);
    fprintf(fout, "\n");

    // 입력 파일을 처음으로 되돌리고 삭제할 노드를 찾아서 삭제
    rewind(fin);
    while (fscanf(fin, "%d", &key) != EOF) {
        rbnode* n = searchNode(root, key);
        if (n != NULL) {
            delete(&root, n);
        }
    }

    // 삭제 후 결과 출력
    fprintf(fout, "");
    printInorder(root, fout);
    fprintf(fout, "\n");

    fprintf(fout, "");
    printLevelorder(root, fout);
    fprintf(fout, "\n");

    // 파일 닫기
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    // Red-Black Tree의 메모리 해제
    freeRBTree(root);

    return 0;
}

If i insert the txt file and run the code, the result 2 lines output well after installing in output.txt, but after deleting, nothing is output in the result 2 lines. Please solve the problem.
Inorder traversal after insertion: 2 3 6 7 8 10 11 13 18 22 26
Levelorder traversal after insertion: 10 7 18 3 8 11 22 2 6 13 26 
Inorder traversal after deletion: 
Levelorder traversal after deletion: 

Like this...
I don't know how to solve it

Not sure if I understand the question, but surely if you delete all the nodes that you inserted, there will be no tree left to print?

how to solve this problem...?

Could you supply the contents of the txt file for reproducing the output you have given? (The levelorder traversal will depend on the order that the input numbers are added to the tree.)
